# VBA delete rows when there is blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am a newbie in VBA so i find difficulties in my task.

I have an excel with 2500 rows and three columns A, B, C.
I need to delete the entire row **only if the value in column C is blank**.
I searched similar questions but they do not apply in my task.

I found this code but does not do the job for my case:

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows1()

'Deletes the entire row within the selection if the ENTIRE row contains no data.

'We use Long in case they have over 32,767 rows selected.

Dim i As Long 

'We turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False

'We work backwards because we are deleting rows.

For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

I would prefer to do this with VBA, while i have to do this for 50 excel files every day.

Any idea of doing this?

Comment: I just asked for help, not for the solution! But thanks anyway for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the comment you're asking for help

I'm assuming the last row is always 2500 as per your post (if not, [this post shows how to get the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180/how-can-i-find-last-row-that-contains-data-in-the-excel-sheet-with-a-macro) )

Then you loop through each row, starting with the last row.

If the row has a value in C column, do nothing. Otherwise delete it.

Spoiler alert: how to do it With comments to explain what it's doing

```
Sub doIt()    
 Dim MyRange As Range
 Dim lngLastRow As Long    
    Set MyRange = Range("A:C") ' grab the range    
    lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, MyRange.Column).End(xlUp).Row  ' grab the last value, swap it for 2500        
    Dim i As Integer        
    For i = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1 ' loop through, starting at the last column        
        If Range("C" & i).Value = "" Then ' test if there is not a value
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete   'delete!
        End If        
    Next i
End Sub
```